# How do I add a data point to an already existing line graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an already existing line graph with monthly data from an excel worksheet.  How to I add the next month's data to the worksheet?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, what version of Excel, and how your data is laid out. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data to the range where the original data is and make sure the chart is pulling from the entire range. Right click the line and click select data then edit the range.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. A common mistake new users make is to answer without details of how to actually resolves the issue. Answers should be detailed and include references, as needed. Please take a few minutes to edit your answer to include details of why your answer is valid. If you need some help, read [How do I write a good answer?](//superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).